# No Desktop icons on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, desktop-icons

With Ubuntu 17.10, is it possible to display our desktop icons as in Windows or Apple and how? Even with GNOME and Unity Tweak Tools installed,all we can get are the trash can and personal files folder icons that's all.

"Desktop icons" is on in GNOME Tweaks and still cannot drag or put Firefox, Chromium, etc from the dock to desktop as it should... the dragged icons always go back to the dock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply dragging application icons from the dock to desktop won't add application launchers to the desktop. Follow the steps instead:

1. Open *Files*, Click on "**+ Other Locations**" in the sidebar
   [image]
2. Click on "**Computer**" and then navigate to `usr` > `share` > `applications`. You should see icons of installed applications here.
3. Copy an application icon (say, Firefox) and paste to your desktop (or simply drag-&-drop).
4. In desktop it may look something like a file named `firefox.desktop`. Double click the file.
5. A warning window may appear asking you to "*Trust and Launch*". Do it.